# react-bootstrap Module not found when Extending BsPrefixComponent for customizing

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I'm using Create-React-App, Typescript(3.4) and react-bootstrap (1.0 beta) to build a website. I have created a component CustomDropdown, which extends BsPrefixComponent. BsPrefixComponent is imported from 'react-bootstrap/helpers'. But, this failed to compile with Error message:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/CustomDropDown.tsx
>   Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap/helpers' in  'path\to\my\project\bs\src'

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BsPrefixComponent } from 'react-bootstrap/helpers';

interface IProps {
  name: string;
}
export default class CustomDropDown extends BsPrefixComponent<'div', IProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.name}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The strange thing is, when compile manually using `tsc --build tsconfig.js --traceResolution`, I see no error. I checked with the module resolution log, 'react-bootstrap/helpers' is resolved successfully.

Also, no errors shown in my VSCode Editor.

But, it failed when using `npm start` or `npm run build`.

So, is this the wrong way to customize react-bootstrap component, or is there a bug?